# Скачать файл и сделать редирект

Tags: php

```
if (file_exists($fileName)) {
  // сбрасываем буфер вывода PHP, чтобы избежать переполнения памяти выделенной под скрипт
  // если этого не сделать файл будет читаться в память полностью!
  if (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
  }
  // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
  //header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($fileName));
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  //header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  //header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
  readfile($fileName);
  // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю 
}
```

Данный код работает, файл скачивается на ПК. После этого я делаю редирект, который не отрабатывает. Если убрать код на скачивание файла, то редирект работает.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы сработал редирект и скачивание файла?

Comment: редирект - заголовок location, а файл - тело ответа на запрос. нельзя передавать клиенту новые заголовки, если уже начали отдавать тело. но если сразу отдать заголовок, то сработает редирект и скачивать будет нечего. или одно или другое. какая у вас задача? скорее всего её надо решать иначе.

Comment: если у вас там ссылка на скачивание файла, то открывайте ее в `_blank` табе. _зы: забавный коммент про очистку буфера, вы где такое нашли?_

Comment: После изменения таблицы, мы ее сохраняем и скачиваем данную таблицу в csv файл.

Comment: @teran данный код был взят из простор интернета. На данный момент мне нужен рабочий код. Я правильно понял, что данный код про буфер - чушь?

Comment: @Lexx918, спасибо, понял. будем делать по другому